How can I list meetings that I declined in Outlook for Mac?
I use Microsoft Outlook for Mac. Meetings that I declined do not show up in my calendar. How can I find these? How can I change my RSVP?

Go to your "Sent" folder, search for subject:Declined in the Current Folder. You may need to translate the word "Declined" based on your configured language preferences.

The list of search results can be a little easier to parse when you turn of the Conversations view: in the menu bar, select "View" and uncheck "Show as Conversations".
If you want to change your response/RSVP to a meeting invite, you can copy the meeting subject, go to your "Deleted Items" folder, and search for the subject in that folder.
